# VB.NET TIMER if the timer is working, don't start again

Tags: vb.net

I  have a problem.

I have a Timer in my code when is running It have to fill 10 textbox.
My problem is never finish because the timer start again and again.

Can you help mes, please?

```
                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Tiempo" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>





Protected Sub Tiempo_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tiempo.Tick
    tempo()
End Sub

Public Sub tempo()
    Dim kepserver As New Kepserver
    Dim Tag As New BDD_TagsTableAdapters.TagTableAdapter
    Dim Maq As New BDD_TagsTableAdapters.MaquinasTableAdapter

    Tiempo.Interval = 50000000


    Dim num_Maq As Integer
    Dim nomtag As String

    'MsgBox(PlcMaquina)

    Tiempo.Enabled = False

    num_Maq = Maq.Id_Maquina(PlcMaquina)

    ''Tipo 2 porque controla el PLC lectura
    If txtgcaspre1.Text = "" Then
        nomtag = Tag.Saber_tag(num_Maq, Alias_S1_CAV1, ControlTagControl)
        txtgcaspre1.Text = kepserver.LeerKepserverInteger(nomtag.TrimEnd)
        If txtgcaspre1.Text <> "" Then Tiempo.Enabled = False

        'MsgBox(txtgcaspre1.Text)
    End If

    If txtgcaspre2.Text = "" Then
        nomtag = Tag.Saber_tag(num_Maq, Alias_S1_CAV2, ControlTagControl)
        txtgcaspre2.Text = kepserver.LeerKepserverInteger(nomtag.TrimEnd)
        '' MsgBox(txtgcaspre2.Text)
    End If



    If txtgcaspre3.Text = "" Then
        nomtag = Tag.Saber_tag(num_Maq, Alias_S1_CAV3, ControlTagControl)
        txtgcaspre3.Text = kepserver.LeerKepserverInteger(nomtag.TrimEnd)
        'MsgBox(txtgcaspre3.Text)

    End If


    If txtgcaspre4.Text = "" Then
        nomtag = Tag.Saber_tag(num_Maq, Alias_S1_CAV4, ControlTagControl)
        txtgcaspre4.Text = kepserver.LeerKepserverInteger(nomtag.TrimEnd)
        ' MsgBox(txtgcaspre4.Text)
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: We can't do anything until you post the code that you are running

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the timer in the tick event.

```
Protected Sub Tiempo_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tiempo.Tick
  Tiempo.Enabled = False 'Prevent timer from running another tick_event    
  tempo()
End Sub
```

I also don't understand why you set a timer interval in tempo() ? 
That seems unnecessary. What is your motivation here?